# What does matrix transposition represent?

Tags: matrices, soft-question

If the visual manifestation of a matrix is a linear transformation, what is that of its transpose?

Comment: It corresponds to the adjoint of that linear transformation.  If $A: X \rightarrow Y$ is a linear map between two (real) vector spaces, then $A^T: Y^* \rightarrow X^*$ is defined by $\langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, A^T y \rangle$ for all $x \in X$.

Comment: @Widawensen The duplicates have many answers, also about "visual manifestations" in the cited duplicate.